# Casting value from pow/powl to Long Long in C

Tags: c, int, long-integer, pow, math.h

In C, I am trying a few different things, but am not sure which is most efficient. I am trying to have a power function returns

Originally I had

```
long long rhs = num % (long long) pow(10, pos);
```

but this gave errors as the power became high.

I substituted `powl` to return a `long double`, which works flawlessly in returning powers up to the largest value of `long long`

```
long long rhs = num % (long long) powl(10, pos);
```

However, I am worried that this may not be the most efficient way to 
get powers of 10, which are reused in other parts of the programs.

For getting powers of ten to divide a long long up to its maximum 
value, should I continue using the powl cast to long long method or
use a function that only returns long long like i did below. Which
is more efficient?

```
long long pow10(int exp)
{
 long long pow = 1;

 for(exp = exp; exp > 0; exp--)
 {

   pow *= 10;
 }

  return pow;

}//pow10
```

Comment: Note that your `pow10()` function is only good got positive values of `exp`.

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise, a look-up table will be fastest:

```
long long pow10( unsigned int )
{
    static const long long lookup[]
    { 
        1LL, 
        10LL, 
        100LL, 
        1000LL, 
        10000LL, 
        1000000LL,
        10000000LL, 
        100000000LL, 
        1000000000LL, 
        10000000000LL, 
        100000000000LL, 
        1000000000000LL, 
        10000000000000LL, 
        100000000000000LL, 
        1000000000000000LL, 
        10000000000000000LL, 
        100000000000000000LL, 
        1000000000000000000LL 
    } ; 

    return( lookup[exp] ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use divide and conquer. This won't be faster than a pure table look up, but it doesn't need to be modified if the width of `long long` changes, either. If you want to detect overflow, you will need *log<sub>10</sub>*(`ULLONG_MAX`), and compare the incoming `exp` argument against it.

```
unsigned long long pow10 (int exp) {
    static long long odd[] = { 1, 10 };
    unsigned long long x = 10;
    unsigned long long y = 1;
    while (exp > 1) {
        x *= x;
        y *= odd[exp % 2];
        exp /= 2;
    }
    return (exp > 0) ? x * y : !exp;
}
```

Comment: Note: to do `log10(ULLONG_MAX)`, one use `#define Exp10_MAX ((int) (sizeof unsigned long long * CHAR_BIT*0.3011))`